# Flex 3.6 - null object reference during null check

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, nullpointerexception

I'm stuck with a weird problem. My air application stops the execution with this error:

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a 
null object reference.
at myapp::MyObject/myFunction()  
   [C:\cygwin\home\pathtomyapp\myComponent.mxml:556]
...
```

Line 556 is the following:

```
if (xmlGeoSearchResult == null) return;
```

The latter variable is declared in the head of the file like this:

```
[Bindable]
private var xmlGeoSearchResult:XMLListCollection = null;
```

How can this be possible ? I know the variable can be null , hence i put a check for it, but it seems it triggers an error in any case .

**UPDATE**

I got rid of the above error, by fixing a part of code totally unrelated with `xmlGeoSearchResult` variable. It was a `google maps` init problem.

Anyway i would like to know if the check for a null value could be invalid or it's a flex bug.

I did some test (with the original non-fixed code) like you guys suggested.

I put a trace just before the like 556 like this

```
trace("HELLOOOOOOOOO I'M RECOMPILED");

if (xmlGeoSearchResult == null) return;
```

and the string was traced (proving that it was correctly compiled)

I also tried to remove the `null init` for the `xmlGeoSearchResult` declaration but nothing changed.

Comment: Are you dead sure that's line number 556 ?

Comment: I'm super-dead sure. I'm getting crazy

Comment: Did you try to define and see if `private var xmlGeoSearchResult:XMLListCollection = new XMLListCollection()` solves the problem ?

Comment: Perhaps replace the condition with `if (!xmlGeoSearchResult) return;`

Comment: Did your changes get re-compiled correctly? Try putting a trace call somewhere before this error happens to make sure.

Comment: @NoobUnChained There is no difference between `if ( !varName )` and `if ( varName == null )`. They should always produce the same result. There may be a time difference, but it would be minuscule if there is.

Comment: Have you stepped through your code?  I suspect there is something off with how you initialize the xmlGeoSearchResult.  How about you remove the '= null' from the variable creation statement and re-run your code?

Comment: I did the test you suggested me guys... No luck